# Public functions become remotely accessible when implementing onCFCRequest()

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

**SOME BACKGROUND:**

I'm using `onCFCRequest()` to handle remote CFC calls separately from regular CFM page requests. This allows me to catch errors and set MIME types cleanly for all remote requests.

**THE PROBLEM:**

I accidentally set some of my remote CFC functions to `public` access instead of `remote` and realized that they were still working when called remotely.

As you can see below, my implementation of `onCFCRequest()` has created a gaping security hole into my entire application, where **an HTTP request could be used to invoke any `public` method on any HTTP-accessible CFC.**

**REPRO CODE:**

In Application.cfc:

```
    public any function onCFCRequest(string cfc, string method, struct args){
        cfc = createObject('component', cfc);
        return evaluate('cfc.#method#(argumentCollection=args)');
    }
```

In a CFC called remotely:

```
    public any function publicFunction(){
        return 'Public function called remotely!';
    }
```

**QUESTION:**

I know I could check the meta data for the component before invoking the method to verify it allows remote access, but are there other ways I could approach this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`onCfcRequest()` doesn't really create the security hole, *you* create the security hole by blindly running the method without checking to see if it's appropriate to do so first, I'm afraid ;-)

(NB: I've fallen foul of exactly the same thing, so I'm not having a go @ you ;-)

So - yeah - you *do* need to check the metadata before running the method. That check is one of the things that CF passes back to you to manage in its stead when you use this handler, and has been explicitly implemented as such (see [3039293](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3039293)).

I've written up a description of the issue and the solution on my [blog](http://adamcameroncoldfusion.blogspot.co.uk/2013/04/its-easy-to-create-security-hole-in.html). As observed in a comment below I use some code in there - `invoke()` - that will only work on CF10+, but the general technique remains the same.

Comment: Obviously it's my implementation that's the problem here. Looping over the metadata for every remote request seems like it would introduce a lot of expensive overhead. Function meta data is held in an array (no shortcut for grabbing it from a struct key), and if the CFC is extending another CFC, I'll have to continue up the inheritance chain, checking every one of the methods to find (or not find) the right one. Blech.

Comment: You just need to check whether the method being called is remote or not, surely? I'm in the middle of blogging about this (thanks for the inspiration). Will update my answer with the link shortly (+1h, I imagine).

Comment: @imthepitts if you use `GetComponentMetaData()` you get less overhead (it's static).  Or alternatively, pick a convention of naming the remote methods then you can do a quick check in the method name.

Comment: @AdamCameron, yes, I do just need to check whether the method is remote, but that requires looping over the functions meta data array and checking the name and the access of the function. And if the function being called is coming from the super CFC, I then have to get its function meta data and continue looping in the same manner. To top it off, there's that stupid bug in the meta data arrays that won't allow a nice `for (var i in functions){}` style loop. Do you know of a simpler way to get that information?

Comment: Actually, @Henry, you may be on to something. I should be able to use the naming convention of the component itself, as they all contain "RemoteService" and will only contain remote functions. So, `if not 'RemoteService', disallow remote access.` Or something.

Comment: @imthepitts that would work too. Like: `ListFindNoCase("RemoteServiceA,RemoteServiceB", arguments.cfc)`

Comment: @imthepitts you can short-circuit the looping easily enough, but yeah... the inheritance thing is giving me pause for thought. But I'll get back to you shortly.

Comment: Thanks, @AdamCameron. It hadn't occurred to me that I could get the meta data directly on the method being invoked. Super simple and elegant.

Comment: Actually it didn't occur to me either until I was just about to press "send" on that article. Then I had a whole heap of revision to do.. oops! It was good to be prompted to do the investigation!

Comment: For those who are still on CF9 or earlier, the "invoke" method used in Adam's blog post wasn't added until CF10.

Comment: Good point. Usually `evaluate()` is probably as good a wake as any of dealing with this on CF9.